# Simple clarification on javac command

Tags: java, javac

I am studying Ant scripts in Java reading this Hello World tutorial: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

In the previous tutorial it create a new directory by DOS **md src** command (mkdir in Linux)

then put the following simple code into: **src\oata\HelloWorld.java**:

```
package oata;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Now it compile it by this shell statment:

```
md build\classes
javac -sourcepath src -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.java
java -cp build\classes oata.HelloWorld
```

I know that **javac** compile the classess but what exactly do this line?

```
javac -sourcepath src -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.java
```

I think that I am sayng to javac that **src** is where are the sources class to compile, then the **-d** say that **build\classes** i the path where to put the compiled class

But what it means the final: **src\oata\HelloWorld.java**?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the filename(s) to compile.

The purpose of the -sourcepath option is to tell the compiler where the source files for *dependent* classes may be found. It doesn't imply that everything in that directory should be compiled.